# Preview Custom View integration- Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

The custom view is not displaying on my camera preview. Can't figure out the reason.Code runs fine, only the circle is not drawing on it.Googled it as well but no help yet.

**Main Class**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

md = (MyDrawing)findViewById(R.id.Drawing);

myContext = this;
initialize();
}
```

}

**XML Class**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="404dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|bottom">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="348dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Capture/Stop"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        />

</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="504dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample.MyDrawing
        android:id="@+id/Drawing"
        android:layout_width="192dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

**Custom View**

```
  public class MyDrawing extends View {

  Canvas canvas;
  int w;
  int h;

  private static final int DEFAULT_CIRCLE_COLOR = Color.RED;

  private int circleColor = DEFAULT_CIRCLE_COLOR;
  private Paint paint;

  public MyDrawing(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init(context, null);
  }



public MyDrawing(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
{
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

private void onMeasure()
{
     w = getWidth()/2;
     h = getHeight()/2;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    super.onDraw(canvas);

   // int w = getWidth()/2;
   // int h = getHeight()/2;

    int pl = getPaddingLeft();
    int pr = getPaddingRight();
    int pt = getPaddingTop();
    int pb = getPaddingBottom();

    int usableWidth = w - (pl + pr);
    int usableHeight = h - (pt + pb);

    int radius = Math.min(usableWidth, usableHeight) / 2;
    int cx = pl + (usableWidth / 2);
    int cy = pt + (usableHeight / 2);

    paint.setColor(circleColor);
    canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
}


}
```

Comment: are you getting value of cx ,cy and radius value correct ? What is the color of paint? Can you please post the code so that We can proceed further

Comment: Detail added. cx and cy are constant so far. Paint is RED. It is showing on layout xml file if i remove onMeasure() and decomment, onDraw() lines. But on running, no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer order was what i was missing. Just used Relative Layout and changed it in Main Activity code as well. Results were "EUREKA" !

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:baselineAligned="false">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="303dp"
    android:layout_height="470dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Drawing">

</FrameLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="393dp"
    android:layout_height="92dp"
    android:text="Capture/Stop"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample.MyDrawing
    android:id="@+id/Drawing"
    android:layout_width="500dp"
    android:layout_height="507dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    />


  </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace

```
private void onMeasure()
{
     w = getWidth()/2;
     h = getHeight()/2;
}
```

with

```
@Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        w = getWidth()/2;
        h = getHeight()/2;
    }
```

Comment: No change, still not displaying the RED circle. 
md = (MyDrawing)findViewById(R.id.Drawing); is this line integration my view class righty ? And does the xml need some fix ?

Comment: The XML code u posted is it the content activity_main ??

Comment: Yes its the activity_main.xml  On it i can see the red circle drawn. But when code debugs it dont show up.

Comment: Check detailed XML. i have edited it, its complete now.

Comment: Did u replace  the onMeasureMethod ?? Also what is the package of MyDrawing class ?? U need to override onMeasure with protected access specifier and it should accept two parameter as I posted Above

Comment: Yes i did exactly same as you told for onMeasure. It is "package com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample" .  I have a lot of changes according to my need in it.

Comment: Nitin. i found that circle is displayed but its under the camera preview. How to set it up

Comment: If u can please put complete code we wil be able to figure it out .

Comment: Problem is in XML file, i have posted it complete.By making camera preview of half size and Putting  <com.javacodegeeks.androidvideocaptureexample.MyDrawing... TAG outside camerapreview in xml,  displayed circle. But the above xml so far is not showin it. Can you figure out xml problem plz.